# Angular 2: Populating components to template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic2

I'm on Angular2 RC/Ionic2 trying to populate a div with buttons from an array of strings, and attach click handlers for each button added. So far I've been successful with the following:

```
onPageLoaded() {
    array.forEach(function (item){
        let element = document.createElement("button");
        element.setAttribute('id', item);
        element.innerHTML = item;
        let container = document.getElementById("button-container");
        container.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

Visually, everything seems to work fine. However, when I try to append a click handler with either this:

```
element.setAttribute('(click)', myFunction());
```

or this:

```
element.onclick(myFunction());
```

The buttons do not appear. I do note that this is the "traditional" way to introduce objects into the DOM. Could there be an Angular way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you do this in Angular2 and this doesn't work at all. Angular doesn't process (resolve `()`, `[]`, `{{}}` bindings or instantiate components or directives) for HTML that is added dynamically in any way.

The Angular way is like

```
<div id="button-container">
  <button *ngFor="let item of array" [attr.id]="item" (click)="myFunction(item)">{{item}}</button>
</div>
```

`<div id="button-container">` is not necessary, I just added it because it was mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I would leverage the associated template to do that and not work directly on the DOM (Angular2 will do that for you):

```
<template ngFor [ngForOf]="array" #element>
  <button (click)="myFunction($event)" [innerHTML]="element"></button>
</template>
```

Using the desugared expression isn't necessarily needed but depends on what output you expect. You could have directly the following:

```
<button *ngFor="let element of array"
   (click)="myFunction($event)" [innerHTML]="element"></button>
```

Moreover I don't know what you have in the `element` variable but if it's not HTML, you can directly use interpolation as described below:

```
<button *ngFor="let element of array"
   (click)="myFunction($event)" [attr.id]="element">{{element}}</button>
```